# JDK issue with Eclipse Neon on my Windows 7 desktop

Tags: java, eclipse, java-home, eclipse-neon, jdk1.7

On my Windows 7 64 bit desktop, I have the following JDK installed to the following directory:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_80

I downloaded Eclipse Neon (eclipse-jee-neon-2-win32-x86_64) to my desktop.

In System Variables, "JAVA_HOME" is currently set "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_80".

If I set PATH "%JAVA_HOME%" then double clicked eclipse.exe, I receieved the following error:
[image]

then it exited.

If I set PATH "%JAVA_HOME%\bin" then double clicked eclipse.exe, I receieved the following error:
[image]

then it exited.

Then I added the following lines to the top of the eclipse.ini file,

```
-vm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin\javaw.exe
```

and double clicked eclipse.exe, it showed the following error:
[image]

followed by the following error message:

[image]

I am sure there was something wrong with the setting of the JDK path but am unable to figure out where went wrong.

Comment: You have downloaded a 32-bit version (it's installed in `Program File (x86)`), do one of: download the 64-bit version of the JRE (eclipse includes a compiler, you **can** get the JDK if you prefer - for example, to compile with maven at the command line), or download the 32-bit version of eclipse. Windows doesn't allow you to mix 32-bit and 64-bit native code (and eclipse includes native code for the UI).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thanks. Isn't the "eclipse-jee-neon-2-win32-x86_64" that I downloaded a 32-bit Eclipse?

Comment: For your info, I have another Eclipse which is an 32-bit Indigo. It works well with the 32 bit JDK that was installed. I need to have both Indigo and Neon installed and work on my desktop.

Comment: No. The "x86_64" is 64-bit.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch. Oh, my fault, I will give it a go.

Comment: Does the "PATH" variable need to be set "%JAVA_HOME%\bin"?

Comment: Yes, you should set  your path variable pointing to JDK/bin.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install 64 bit of `JDK` or `JRE` in order to run also you have to set JAVA_HOME path to 64 bit `JDK` or `JRE` and refer [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ia6HC3vxMXg)